# How to use Html.TextBox value with Controller and Html.Action?

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Let's say I have a view contains a product which any user can purchase and order. So in this view there is a button: 'Add to cart', description of the product, amount to order of the product. In this view, the user can select the amount via Html.TextBox, then the user can order it by clicking on 'Add to cart'. So I've been trying to code it but I'm not sure how correct the code is (The script is the problem)...

Notice that my controller function has two args: the product itself (there is a model for product) and the amount (integer).
Well, I had no problems with the product, but once I started using also the amount, it became way more complicated.

Here is my code attached:

```
@*@model SurffingSite.Models.Products*@
```

@model List

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DisplayAllProducts";
}
```

Our products

```
    <div class="row">

        @foreach (var product in Model)
        {

            <figure class="portfolio-item col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <img src="~/images/@product.Picture" class="img-responsive" />
                <div class="product-details">
                    <h2 class="product-name">Products Name: @product.ProductName</h2>
                    <label>Category: @product.Category</label>
                    <div class="product-description">Description: @product.Description</div>
                    <div class="product-price">Price: @product.Price ₪</div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter amount:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input type="text" name="amounter" id="amounter" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>


                        <a id="btn_add" href="" data-id ="@product" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" style="margin-left:60px">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Add to cart
                        </a><br />


                        <a id="btn_more_info" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" style="margin-left:60px">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Read more
                        </a>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </figure>
        }
    </div>
</section>

<script>
    $(".btn btn-info btn-lg").click(function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = '@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Cart", new {prod = "product", amount = "theamounter"})';
        url = url.replace("theamounter", $("#amounter").val());
        url = url.replace("product", $(this).data());
        window.location.href = url;
    });
</script>
```

Here is the relevant controller method:
https://pastebin.com/FX5jGAuZ

and here is my model for a product object:
https://pastebin.com/FgJ0u51P

Comment: If your view is strongly typed to a single Product, What are you trying to achieve with `foreach (var product in Model)` line ?

Comment: and you do not need to send the entire product object. All you need is the productId

Comment: There are many products in the view.. I just wanted to simplify it.. So the foreach stands for displaying all the products..

For your second comment- Why don't I need the entire object? In my controller I do use the entire object..

Comment: You should post the correct code! Posting only relevant part is good, but post correct code. Why do you need the entire object in your action method ? Why not just productId ?

Comment: ok I just updated ..

Comment: For a start it should be a POST, not a GET

Comment: Could you expain what you mean? because I can't find the relevant part in my code for what you said